# Eclipse PDT: show every call of function

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Is there an option in Eclipse PDT to show every call of chosen function.
I now if you select some kind of function and hit F3 key you will see a definition of selected function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Search Menu, Choose 'Search...', and navigate to the PHP tab, then

- Enter the method name in the search string text box;
- Select Method in the Search for group;
- Select References in the Limit to group.

[Find method usages http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/83/eclipsepdtfindmethodusa.png](http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/83/eclipsepdtfindmethodusa.png)

Answer (score 1):

We have a plugin for that... [nWire for PHP](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-php). It's a comprehensive PHP code analyzer which represents all your code associations, invocations included in one quick and easy to use view. It can also represent the associations graphically.